# FB php-graph-sdk's getLoginUrl is asking for more permissions than requested

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using v5.6.2 and my code is this:

`$permissions = ['email'];
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(base_url() . '/account/connect_facebook2/fbcallback', $permissions);`

Although I am only asking for the user's e-mail, I get the following message from Facebook:

" will receive: your name and profile picture, friend list, birthday, current city, photos, videos and email address."  with the following warning:

"Submit for Login Review. Some of the permissions below have not been approved for use by Facebook.
Submit for review now or learn more. "

What could be wrong?

Comment: So what does the login URL actually look like? (Not necessarily the whole thing, but the part with the `scope` parameter.)

Comment: It's "scope=email".